# Most elegant way to wait for async initialization in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class that is responsible for all my API/Database queries. All the calls as well as the initialization of the class are async methods.

The contract I'd like to offer is that the caller has to call [initialize] as early as possible, but they don't have to await for it, and then they can call any of the API methods whenever they need later.

What I have looks roughly like this:

```
class MyApi {

  late final ApiConnection _connection;
  late final Future<void> _initialized;

  void initialize(...) async {
    _initialized = Future<void>(() async {
      // expensive initialization that sets _connection
    });
    await _initialized;
  }

  Future<bool> someQuery(...) async {
    await _initialized;
    // expensive async query that uses _connection
  }

  Future<int> someOtherQuery(...) async {
    await _initialized;
    // expensive async query that uses _connection
  }

}
```

This satisfies the nice contract I want for the caller, but in the implementation having those repeated `await _initialized;` lines at the start of every method feel very boilerplate-y. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what "expensive initialization" includes?

Comment: Short of using code-generation, I don't think so.  However, I personally would declare `_connection` as `Future<ApiConnection>`.  That would allow you to remove `_initialized`, and then all of your API functions would be naturally forced to use `await _connection`, which would be much less error-prone.

Comment: @jamesdlin In that case, every method would have to start with `await _connection.then((connection) { // expensive query that uses connection }`. That feels even more boilerplate-y than what I currently have. Why do you think that would be less error-prone?

Comment: To support @jamesdlin's argument, have a look at some other Flutter APIs (packages). For example, Firebase does this: `await Firebase.initializeApp()`. It is more semantically clear that when you do `api = await ApiConnection()` you're waiting for the API to initialize, and when you do `result = await  api.someQuery()` you're only waiting for the query itself. In your current approach, it is not clear that `someQuery` also has a "hidden" cost of waiting for the API initialization.

Comment: @user18184 No, every function would start with `var connection = await _connection;`. It's less error-prone because code that neglects to do that would not compile.  In contrast, with your current approach, code that neglects to do `await _initialized;` would fail at *runtime* with a `LateInitializationError` when trying to use `_connection` prematurely, and that could easily go unnoticed if your API methods are called in different orders where some orderings happen to work but others fail.

Comment: @jamesdlin Makes sense. And it’s actually less boilerplate than I thought, because I can do stuff like `return (await _connection).make_expensive_query(…);`. Thanks! If you post your advice as an answer (not a comment) I’d be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of using code-generation, I don't think there's a good way to automatically add boilerplate to all of your methods.

However, depending on how `_connection` is initialized, you perhaps instead could change:

> ```dart
>   late final ApiConnection _connection;
>   late final Future<void> _initialized;
> ```

to something like:

```dart
  late final Future<ApiConnection> _connection = _initializeConnection(...);
```

and get rid of the `_initialized` flag.  That way, your boilerplate would change from:

> ```dart
>   Future<bool> someQuery(...) async {
>     await _initialized;
>     // expensive async query that uses `_connection`
> ```

to:

```dart
  Future<bool> someQuery(...) async {
    var connection = await _connection;
    // expensive async query that uses `connection`
```

This might not look like much of an improvement, but it is significantly less error-prone.  With your current approach of using `await _initialized;`, any method that accidentally omits that could fail at runtime with a `LateInitializationError` when accessing `_connection` prematurely.  Such a failure also could easily go unnoticed since the failure would depend on the order in which your methods are called.  For example, if you had:

```dart
Future<bool> goodQuery() async {
  await _initialized;
  return _connection.doSomething();
}

Future<bool> badQuery() async {
  // Oops, forgot `await _initialized;`.
  return _connection.doSomething();
}
```

then calling

```dart
var result1 = await goodQuery();
var result2 = await badQuery();
```

would succeed, but

```dart
var result2 = await badQuery();
var result1 = await goodQuery();
```

would fail.

In contrast, if you can use `var connection = await _connection;` instead, then callers would be naturally *forced* to include that boilerplate.  Any caller that accidentally omits the boilerplate and attempts to use `_connection` directly would fail at *compilation* time by trying to use a `Future<ApiConnection>` as an `ApiConnection`.